# want to ignore duplicate raws on group result

Tags: mysql, sql

Result Right Now , want to ignore dulicate

```
id_category   name             id_manufacturer   name
6             CLOTH of House   12                Sabb
6             CLOTH of House   12                Sabb 
6             CLOTH of House   14                CTES
8             Sabih Nopoe      12                Sabb
```

I want this Result remove duplicate and heading changes

```
id_category   Man-name         id_manufacturer   Cat-name 
6             CLOTH of House   12                Sabb
6             CLOTH of House   14                CTES
8             Sabih Nopoe      12                Sabb
```

```sql
SELECT
    p.id_category_default,
    c.name,
    p.id_manufacturer,
    d.name    
FROM
    psup_product p    
            INNER JOIN psup_manufacturer d ON
    p.id_manufacturer = d.id_manufacturer    
            INNER JOIN psup_category_lang c ON
    p.id_category_default = c.id_category
    WHERE p.id_category_default > 2    
    GROUP BY p.id_product
ORDER BY p.id_category_default
```

Comment: I've removed all the conflicting tags. Please retag the RDBMS you are using and *only* that one.

Comment: @Qasim Tagging mysql and sql-server is kinda like tagging java and javascript; those are two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code show you're working on PrestaShop table

this code will work please check

```
SELECT
    p.id_category_default,
    c.name as Man-name,
    p.id_manufacturer,
    d.name as Cat-name    
FROM
    psup_product p    
            INNER JOIN psup_manufacturer d ON
    p.id_manufacturer = d.id_manufacturer    
            INNER JOIN psup_category_lang c ON
    p.id_category_default = c.id_category
    WHERE p.id_category_default > 2    
    GROUP BY d.id_manufacturer
ORDER BY c.id_category
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove duplicates by selecting DISTINCT values or by GROUPing. DISTINCT will return only distinct values across all the columns you selected. GROUPing will group rows into summary rows by the fields you group by.

Here either adding DISTINCT after your SELECT statement, or including all the fields in your SELECT statement in your GROUP BY statement should return distinct records. Because you grouped by id_product which is not in the SELECT statement, it will not remove duplicates.

Examples in code would be:

Updating SELECT statement to include DISTINCT

```
SELECT DISTINCT    --Adding DISTINCT keyword
    p.id_category_default,
```

or, updating GROUP BY statement to include all fields in the SELECT statement.

```
GROUP BY    --Removed p.id_product from the grouping and added fields from SELECT statement.
    p.id_category_default,
    c.name,
    p.id_manufacturer,
    d.name
```

Comment: Andrew O'Brien can you please share example from my code.

Comment: Provided examples. You can find additional examples at
DISTINCT: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/t_sql/t_sql_distinct_clause.htm
GROUP BY: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp